# select option not working with ng-model in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a select box where I show elements from a list 
Code Snippet:

```
export class CreateauctionComponent implements OnInit{

    createAuctionForm: FormGroup;
    test:any = ["cat","dog"];

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,private _categories: UserCategoriesForAuctionService){
        //
    }
}
```

In HTML rendered as:

```
<div class="form-col">
    <h5><span style="color:red;">*</span>{{'createAuction.category' | translate}}:</h5>
    <select class="form_cbx long-select" name="" ng-model="test">
        <option  ng-options="t in test">{{t}}</option>
    </select>   
</div>
```

I am not able to see any values. Only one blank field in the list. Can anyone direct what is the issue here?

Comment: Your HTML looks like Angular 1, not Angular 4.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should be,

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedanimal" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let c of test" [ngValue]="c"> {{c}} </option>
</select>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/mKWRBef1Zc66jFfssf36?p=preview)**

Comment: Getting this error:Error trying to diff 'cat'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: It worked . The name of my ngmodel was same as the array

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `compareWith` property on `select` tag, but If you are using angular 4, your html still looks like using angularJs.

**HTML File :**

```
<select [compareWith]="byAnimal" [(ngModel)]="selectedAnimal">  
  <option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [ngValue]="animal">
    {{animal.type}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**TS File**

```
byAnimal(item1,item2){
  return item1.type == item2.type;
}
```

One of the best soltion from this [link](https://www.mbejda.com/angular-4-compare-with/)

Answer (score 0):

Correct Way would be:

```
<select id="select-type-basic" [(ngModel)]="status">
    <option *ngFor="let status_item of status_values">
    {{status_item}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Value Should be avoided inside option since that will set the default value of the 'Select field'. Default Selection should be binded with [(ngModel)] and Options should be declared likewise.

```
status : any = "Completed";
status_values: any = ["In Progress", "Completed", "Closed"];
```