# ngFor works but not ng-options or ng-repeat

Tags: angular, angular5

I created a Angular 5 project.

I created my own component and pass the components html template a list of persons.

The following code works

```
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let x of persons">{{ x.Id }}: {{ x.personName }}</li>
  </ul>
```

I need to put it in a select and not a list.

ng-options doesn't work

```
<select ng-model="selectedPerson" ng-options="x.personName for x in persons"></select>
```

ng-repeat doesn't work

```
<select><option ng-repeat="x in persons">{{x.personName}}</option></select>
```

Both give the following error in the browser.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'personName' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may be helpful - https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this :

in angular 5 use `ngFor` instead of `ng-repeat`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson" name="selectedPerson">
    <option *ngFor="let x of persons">{{x.personName}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That is still using ngFor which works. I would like to make use of ng-options and ng-repeat

Comment: you can't use `ng-options` or `ng-repeat` in latest version of angular. these are use only in angular js ... refer this : https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference

Comment: Hi then that is the answer. My question was why didn't it work? Edit your answer with the reason that it isn't supported in Angular 5 and I will mark it correct

Answer (score -1):

Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `ng-model`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required  [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" />
```

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550964/select-option-not-working-with-ng-model-in-angular-4)