# How pass objects to function in select? Angular 4

Tags: angular

I need to pass object to the function when I change option in select.

```
<select (change)="addToVisibility('type',$event.target.value)">
     <option *ngFor="let type of selectedTypes" [ngValue]="type">
            {{type.title}}
     </option>
</select>
```

I try like this, but always in function pass type.title, but i need to pass type.
Please help me)
P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ngModel with ngModelChange as follows

```
<select [(ngModel)] ="selectedType" (ngModelChange)="addToVisibility(selectedType,$event.target.value)">
     <option *ngFor="let type of selectedTypes" [ngValue]="type">
            {{type.title}}
     </option>
</select>
```

Comment: `"addToVisibility(type,$event.target.value)"`
in this function first argument 'type' is the string, it can be 'company' , 'user' etc.
but I try to do like this
`"addToVisibility('type',type)"` and get undefined value.

Comment: `addToVisibility(type: string, query?: any) {
        console.log(query);
        switch (type) {
            case 'type': { ... `

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: I mean when I pass without single quote i get undefined)

Comment: check the updated answer. reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550964/select-option-not-working-with-ng-model-in-angular-4

Comment: yes, ngModelChange work fine. Thank you!)
but how can I set a first item item value into select when i first time render this element? Now when I use ngModel select text is empty until change option.

Comment: set the initial value in the typescript

Answer (score 3):

```
<select   [(ngModel)] ="selectedType" (ngModelChange)="onSelectChange($event,selectedType)">
    <option>Slect Light Dimmer</option>
<option  [ngValue]="leddim" *ngFor="let leddim of dimmerlightlist">{{leddim.NODE_NAME}} </option>
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer