# Can't get Object from HTMLSelectElement in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
<select #categorySelect (change)="goToCategory.emit(categorySelect.value)" style="...">
    <option selected hidden>All</option>    
    <option 
        [ngValue]="category" 
        *ngFor="let category of categories">
            {{category.groupName}}
        </option>
</select>
```

```
@Output() goToCategory = new EventEmitter<Category>();
```

I want to get the object category but I can only get a string 'object Object' which I can't properly transform back to the object. Is there a way to use native select and get the object element for the function in '(change)'?

Comment: please also add goToCategory type. i guess goTocategory is a string type.

Comment: @Storytellerr Added the code of the method

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589875/how-pass-objects-to-function-in-select-angular-4) help by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a method in the component which will then emit the object value, instead from the template:

Try this:

call new `getCategory` helper method, set `category.id` as an option value, to easily find the object later:

```
<select #categorySelect (change)="getCategory(categorySelect.value)" style="...">


[value]="category.id"
```

Add new method which will find the object and emit it from there:

```
  getCategory(id:string) {
    
    const categorySelect = this.categories.find(el=>el.id === id);

    this.goToCategory.emit(categorySelect);
  }
```

Also, you could use [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#description):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="categorySelect" (change)="goToCategory.emit(categorySelect)" style="...">
```

```
// need to tweak default selected..
categorySelect:Category= this.categories[0]; // or 'All'
```

Comment: Had to change [ngValue] to [value], after that it worked as I expected it to, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize your category object, only string value are usable in a select. So use:

```
[ngValue]="JSON.stringify(category)"
```

And then wherever you want to grab this category (so, in your case the method your Output is emitting to), deserialize the category object by using:

```
methodPointedByTheOutput(serializedCategory:string){    
let category = JSON.parse(serializedCategory) as Category;

//Do something
}
```

Comment: How can I stringify the model in HTML? JSON.stringify throws an error.

Comment: You have to make the JSON api available for your template. Add

public JSON = JSON;

in your Component's properties.