# How to bind [(ngModel)] values in select2 when using angular html and ts file (without Javascript or Jquery)

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, ngmodel

I am trying to add a search option to a dropdown which performs the functionality of autocomplete. I have been given a basic dropdown with select tag.

I tried searching for the following options:
1) I tried to convert my select table into a p-dropdown table using PrimeNG but was unsuccessful.

2) I found select2 option for angular and have been unable to bind the selected value from the dropdown to the ngModel value. The value selected must be retained when navigating between the previous or next pages, however that isn't happening.


3) I tried to convert select table to p-autocomplete as well but do not know how to.
Please guide me with any one of the following ways.

This is the provided select dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedColumnDetails[rowData.rowId]"
   (ngModelChange)="handleChange(rowData.rowId)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of tableColumnDetails[selectedTableDetails[rowData.rowId]]">
          {{option.col_name}}
     </option>
</select>
```

This is what I tried with select2 for angular.

                        
                                {{option.col_name}}

```
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
```

This error is thrown for the following line:

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedColumnDetails[rowData.rowId]
```

Comment: please share your code so the community could help you.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the name attribute along with ngmodel in the same tag

Comment: After assigning name, I get the following error: Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'colName'

Answer (score 0):

`<select>` works slightly differently with ngModel.
Taking your code snippet, Modifying it to pick ControlValue

`<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedColumnDetails[rowData.rowId]"
   (ngModelChange)="handleChange(rowData.rowId)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of tableColumnDetails[selectedTableDetails[rowData.rowId]]" [(ngValue)]="option">
          {{option.col_name}}
     </option>
</select>`

Should work for you.

You should find ample examples provided by angular [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550964/select-option-not-working-with-ng-model-in-angular-4)

Comment: Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable! This is the error I got. Also the code I'm trying to add ngModel for is using <select2>, not <select>

Answer (score 0):

For select2 in Angular, try:

```
<select2 ... [value]="selectedColumnDetails[rowData.rowId]" (valueChanged)="handleChange(rowData.rowId)"></select2>
```

Of course, you would have to update `selectedColumnDetails[rowData.rowId]` inside `handleChange(rowData.rowId)`.

`[(ngModel)]="data"` is short for `[value]="data" (input)="data = $event.target.value"`. Unfortunately the [ng2-select2 package does not support the `input` event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-select2) so you have to write this out in the long form with `valueChanged`.